# Is this stronger conclusion in Hille-Yosida theorem true?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

Let $H$ together with an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $|\cdot|$ be the induced norm. I'm reading *Theorem 7.4 (Hille-Yosida)* in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. Then, given any $u_0 \in D(A)$ there exists a unique function
> $$
> u \in C^1([0,+\infty) ; H) \cap C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))
> $$
> satisfying
> $$
> (6) \quad \begin{cases}
> \frac{d u}{d t}+A u&=0 \quad \text{on} \quad [0,+\infty), \\
> u(0)&=u_0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Moreover,
> $$
> |u(t)| \leq\left|u_0\right| \quad \text { and } \quad\left|\frac{d u}{d t}(t)\right|=|A u(t)| \leq\left|A u_0\right| \quad \forall t \geq 0.
> $$

In above theorem, $D(A)$ in $C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))$ has the subspace topology induced by $|\cdot|$. We define a new inner product on $D(A)$ by
$$
\langle u, v \rangle_{D(A)} := \langle u, v \rangle+\langle Au, Av \rangle.
$$

Then $D(A)$ together with $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{D(A)}$ is a Hilbert space.

> Is it true that the solution $u$ belongs to $C \big ( [0,+\infty) ; (D(A), \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{D(A)}) \big )$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: The topology induced by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{D(A)}$ leads to the norm $\|u\|_1 = \sqrt{|u|^2 + |Au|^2}$. What is the original norm on $D(A)$? And are these two norms perhaps equivalent?

Comment: @HansEngler the original norm on $D(A)$ is the one induced from $H$.

Comment: Write it down! And then compare.

Comment: @HansEngler Maybe I miss something, but I don't see how they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm on $D(A)$ is the graph norm $\|u\|_0 = |u| + |Au|$ or the equivalent Hilbert norm $\|u\|_1 = \sqrt{|u|^2 + |Au|^2}$ which comes from your inner product; see footnote 2 on p. 185 in Brezis' book..

Therefore the answer to your question is **yes**.

Comment: It seems you mis-understood my question. The original norm of $D(A)$ (for $D(A)$ in $C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))$] is that of $H$, i.e., $|\cdot|$. So my interest is in comparing $|\cdot|$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$.

Comment: Are you sure? Take a look how Brezis defines the norm on $D(A)$.

Comment: It seems Brezis does not define any specific norm on $D(A)$. The relevant sentence (at [page 189](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf)) is *"Finally, since $u \in C^1([0,+\infty) ; H)$, the function $t \mapsto A u(t)$ is continuous from $[0,+\infty)$ into $H$ and thus $u \in C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))$"*. My understanding is that $u \in C([0,+\infty) ; H)$ and $u(t) \in D(A)$ for all $t\ge 0$, so $u \in C([0,+\infty) ; D(A))$ where $D(A)$ is endowed with the subspace topology induced from $H$.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: You are right. I missed this important point. Thank you so much for your help!